# Instance not inserting data for widget

Tags: widgets

I am trying to create a widget for my website. This is my first instance of widget creation and I am really unsure as to what the issue is

Here is my code as it stands:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wy_rss_widget' );

function wy_rss_widget() {
    register_widget( 'WY_rss_widget' );
}

class WY_rss_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function WY_rss_widget() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'wy-rss', 'description' => __('A widget for displaying RSS feed', 'wy-rss') );
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'wy-rss-widget' );
        $this->WP_Widget( 'wy-rss-widget', __('RSS Widget', 'wy-rss'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );

        //Our variables from the widget settings.
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $wy_rssURL = $instance['wy_rssURL'];
        $wy_rssLimit = $instance['wy_rssLimit'];

        echo $before_widget;

        // Display the widget title 
        if ( $title ) {
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        }

        //Display the name 
        if ( ( $wy_rssURL != " " || $wy_rssURL != "FEED URL" ) && ( $wy_rssLimit != " " ) ) {
            $rss = new DOMDocument();
            $rss->load($wy_rssURL);
            $feed = array();
            foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
                $item = array ( 
                    'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                    'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                    'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                    'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                );
                array_push($feed, $item);
            }
            $limit = $wy_rssLimit;

            echo '<ul>';
            echo '<li>'.$wy_rssURL.' ('.$limit.')</li>';
            for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
                $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
                $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
                $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
                $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));

                echo '<li>';
                echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
                echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
                echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
                echo '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }

        echo $after_widget;
    }

    //Update the widget 

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        //Strip tags from title and name to remove HTML 
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['wy_rssURL'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['wy_rssURL'] );
        $instance['wy_rssLimit'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['wy_rssLimit'] );

        return $instance;
    }


    function form( $instance ) {

        //Set up some default widget settings.
        $defaults = array( 'title' => __('Title', 'wy-rss'), 'wy_rssURL' => __('FEED URL', 'wy-rss'), 'wy_rssLimit' => __('5','wy-rss') );
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'wp-rss'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'wy_rssURL' ); ?>"><?php _e('URL:', 'wp-rss'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'wy_rssURL' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'wy_rssURL' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['wy_rssURL']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for"<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'wy_rssLimit' ); ?>"><?php _e('Number of items:', 'wp-rss'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'wy_rssLimit' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'wy_rssLimit' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['wy_rssLimit']; ?>" />
        </p>

    <?php
    }
}
```

The value for 'wy_rssLimit' is not being stored, where the values for 'title' and 'wy_rssURL' are. I am really not sure where to look.  Could someone please help?

Comment: Please don't use external sources to add code to your question.

Comment: Many apologies. I thought it would be easier to put it onto PasteBin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `get_field_id` in the name attribute of the "limit" field, where you should be using `get_field_name`. You're actually using `get_field_name` for the name attributes of the other two fields.

Try using

```
name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'wy_rssLimit' ); ?>"
```

instead of

```
name="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'wy_rssLimit' ); ?>"
```

That should solve your issue.

The return values of the `get_field_id` and `get_field_name` methods are different: `get_field_id` constructs a unique ID attribute with dashes, whereas `get_field_name` uses square brackets to construct an array in the request when saving the widget.

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling it would be something simple like that.